# PrestaShop preformence with 100.000 + products

Tags: traffic, load-time, high-traffic, prestashop

I am i the process of finding a replacement for an old web-shop (Compumail.dk), we are looking at a lot of possibility's and one of them is PrestaShop.

The site has in the area of 100.000 products, and we need a solution that can handle this number growing (200.000 - 600.000) in the coming years, i found this: http://blog.egrovesys.com/ecommerce-development/magento-prestashop-latest-comparison 
where it says that it can only handle 25.000 products.

So can a PrestaShop be made to handle 100.000+ products, and preform well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Limitations of SQL based problems can always be altered thought development means. You should ask this on the prestashop forum. Your likely going to get a more catered response.

Comment: +1 the main problem is going to be with the db, to do with scaling the db and making efficient calls, the actual script shouldn't have problems, and there shouldn't be performance issues unless you try and display vast number of products on 1 page, in which case you'd get problems with long executation times.

Comment: @MortenGrue If you're still look for an answer! If you are looking for easy to use and customize cart solution that also scales very well, then I recommend you to try nopCommerce (opensource asp.net based solution). With one performance module (http://nopaccelerate.com/) that integrate very well with Solr, we have scaled it to support more than 20 million products.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so familiar with Prestashop per se, but a company that handles 100,000+ products, probably wants to make sure this works.

The best advice to give here, is to benchmark. Regardless of the solution *(Prestashop or otherwise)*, you probably want to set up a cluster of servers -- if not for load balancing, then for high availability. Write a simple scripts to programmatically add 1M products to the test-webshop, and then use a tool like [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) to benchmark. Depending on the budget, one might invest in more realistic benchmarking-tools (i.e. different user sessions, complexer page requests, etc.).

Then you can make an estimate as to how much server-resources you will need. Then it's up to you (or the company you're working for), if that is acceptable, or if you want to compare it to other solutions. The costs of several [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/?hp=tile)-servers for a few days will probably be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would say don't believe everything you read on the Internet! Second of all, if this ever was true in older versions of Prestashop I can confirm it definately is not an issue in Prestashop v1.6. The optimisation and caching built-in are excellent, and with a well written theme and templating it is possible to have a very fast/responsive store.

I recently had the requirement of a large product catalogue for one of my customers (approx 800,000 products) and already using Prestashop for many other customers, and after reading [dh42: Prestashop Scalability on AWS](http://dh42.com/blog/prestashop-scalability/) I was tempted to give it a try.

I can confirm that by utilising either a content delivery network (CDN) or such as an AWS S3 bucket for images, and a reasonable [AWS RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/details/) instance for the MySQL database (e.g. `db.m3.large` or `db.r3.large`) Prestashop can manage a very large product catalogue without any difficulty and with easy future increased scalability, the only tricky party is getting the AWS instances and configuration setup if you're not familiar with it - this was a steep learning curve for me. I didn't go to the same lengths as were described in the article I referenced but I didn't need to cater for 5000 conconcurrent users either. By the time we worked out the cost of running all the necessary instances on AWS it actually worked out cheaper for us too than the previous VPS hosting arrangement. The site I'm referring to was moved from VPS and published 'live' on AWS in January 2015 and after nearly 5 months I have only been impressed with the final outcome, though it took some serious tweaking in the first month, and we even downgraded our instances from those we originally chose and were still very happy with the performance.

I believe there can still be more work done to improve the scalability of Prestashop, however it is certainly possible at present to get a very fast responding site with a large product catalogue if setup correctly and on hosting infrastructure suitable for the requirements.